# How to dynamically create Java object in C++ Builder?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, c++builder

I have a project in C++ Builder for the Android platform, and I also have a `JAR` file. The `JAR` file contains compiled code consisting of one class with two methods: one static, the other normal. Using the Java2OP utility, a Delphi wrapper was created from a `JAR` file, from which an hpp header was then created.
In C++ code, I was able to easily use a static method from a `JAR` file:

```
TJHelloWorld::JavaClass->getStrStatic();
```

But I don't know how to call a normal method, because for this you need to create an object. How to do it?

Comment: Why you think that you can use java's jar on android platform?

Comment: Because it is possible! For example, I can easily use Java's Toast class to display a message on my smartphone.

Comment: because `Toast` is compiled to Dalvik/ART not to JVM

Comment: Look [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps) and [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Creating_and_Deploying_a_classes.dex_File_Manually#Generating_a_classes.dex_File_from_JAR_Files)

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution:

```
TJHelloWorld::Create()->getStrNoStatic();
```

But to judge how true it is is not in my competence. Will there be a memory leak?

P.S. After correspondence with Remy Lebeau, I came to the conclusion that there will be no memory leak in the given example.

Comment: `Create()` returns a reference-counted object. After the method returns, I'm not sure if that object will automatically drop its refcount to 0 to destroy the object in this example. I don't think it will, at least [not in 10.4 onwards](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New#Unified_Memory_Management). [It might in 10.3 and earlier](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_C%2B%2B), though.

Comment: In any case, you really should use `TJHelloWorld::JavaClass->init()` instead to call the actual Java constructor to instantiate an object. That will return a `_di_JHelloWorld` that will manage the refcount correctly. Otherwise, you can assign the result of `Create()` to a `_di_JHelloWorld` variable to maintain the refcount.

Comment: This code causes an error at runtime:

`_di_JHelloWorld inst = TJHelloWorld::JavaClass->init();
_di_JString jstr = inst->getStrNoStatic(StringToJString(Edit1->Text));
Label2->Text = JStringToString(jstr);`

Comment: Should have worked. Hard to say without seeing the original Java class. Did you try `_di_JHelloWorld inst = TJHelloWorld::Create();`?

Comment: Yes, the code you showed works. [Here](https://pastebin.com/sj4svRnt) is the original Java code.
It is not clear to me why you think the code is `TJHelloWorld::Create()->getStrNoStatic();` will leak memory. `Create()` will create an unnamed object of type `_di_JHelloWorld`, which has a reference count of 1. After calling `getStrNoStatic` and the expression completes, the unnamed object will die, the reference count will become 0 and `DelphiInterface` will release resources.

Comment: "*It is not clear to me why you think the code is `TJHelloWorld::Create()->getStrNoStatic();` will leak memory*" - because it has been a long time since I last saw what the output of Java2OP looks like, and I don't have a compiler installed at the moment to look it up, so I wasn't sure if `Create()` would return a `TJHelloWorld*` raw pointer or a `_di_JHelloWorld` managed interface